# Permission denied error[Error 13] in python while copyig file

Tags: python-2.7

I want to copy a file using shutil.copyfile

```
src =  "C:\Users\Abdur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exam System\dist\Exam_System.war"
dest = "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\webapps"
if os.path.isdir(dest):
        dst = os.path.join(dest, os.path.basename(src))
         shutil.copyfile(src, dest)
```

but it gives following exception:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\\webapps\\Exam_System.war'
```

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to write to `C`. If that is not the problem, then probably `Exam_System.war` is already in use.

Comment: try running as administrator

Comment: What's the windows version? If you start _python_, what's the 1st line that it displays?

Comment: thanks. its working as administrator.